# Поместить JFrame в центр

Tags: java, jframe

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы JFrame располагался в центре, а не в левом верхнем углу, как на скрине:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
final int h = 600;
final int w = 600;

QScreen screen = new QScreen(w, h, 24);
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setResizable(true);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.add(screen);
f.setTitle("Example");
f.setSize(w, h);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JFrame` по-умолчанию использует `BorderLayout`, который растягивает компоненты на все доступное пространство. Проще всего, думаю, взять [`java.awt.GridBagLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html), примерно так:

```
// ... //
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(
        0, 0, // x, y в сетке
        1, 1, // ширина и высота в сетке
        0, 0, // веса
        GridBagConstraints.CENTER, // привязка внутри занятого места в сетке
        GridBagConstraints.NONE,   // растяжение
        new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0),    // отступы от границ компонента до границ места в сетке
        0, 0  // внутренние отступы (компонент займет не меньше минимального размера + отступ 
    );
f.setLayout( new GridBagLayout() );
f.add(screen, gbc);

f.setTitle("Example");
// ... //
```